# node.js - full mysql output for the query - where is it?

Tags: node.js

I can connect to mysql ok.
i want to get the full raw data 
of the query. 
in python i think all data is stored in

```
rows[0]
```

i am not certain how it is in node.js

i want to print the full mysql output
i want to assign it to the variable "bb"

```
connection.connect();

var queryString = 'SELECT * FROM 1_accounts';

connection.query(queryString, function(err,rows,fields){
bb = rows[0].toString();
}); 

connection.end();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see a text representation of `rows` use `JSON.stringify(rows)` instead of `rows.toString()`